# Ionic Camera App crashing in Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

i am developing ionic 1 camera app and Getting Crash with `Samsung Galaxy s4` when using camera or gallery. for camera/gallery using [cordova camera](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) plugin.I am using below camera options:

```
var options = {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: sourceType,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            targetWidth: 250,
            quality : 50,
            correctOrientation:true
          };
```

App working good with other devices.

Comment: Any errors in console before crashing and how your debugging your crash??

Comment: i am tracking with chrome console and timeline. also i have check with android studio, after capture image and press ok, app get restart every-time. there are no error in console. but memory heap get almost full after launch camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot debug i was sure this issue is related to device memory heap. I did write to cordova camera plugin team for the [issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12676).

They suggest me to respect [Android OS life-cycle](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#lifecycle-guide) and it help me to understand reason for crash and solution to get this fix with Cordova 5.1.0+

I will give a try on it, hope this will help to peoples.